# Histogram wont print with large box widths? R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Yesterday, I was asked about how to plot all the occurrences of NA as a histogram over the position. With the help of many others, we were able to figure out a way using ggplot that worked out nice and quickly. Using the same code on my larger dataset (roughly 4200 rows) I was able to generate a histogram. One problem I can't seem to fix is when I'm trying to adjust the box width, currently the boxes are only slivers with a bin width of 300 (roughly the minimum r will allow without the error "bin widths are too small"), when I try to increase the bin width up from there the graph simply won't pop up, the code will run but no graph will pop up. Im not sure what exactly is going on. Please see below the code, the first 20 lines of the table, and the graph in question.

```
  position Imp15 Imp19
1    163302     1    NA
2    163366     1     1
3    163370     1     1
4    163387     1     1
5    163432     0    NA
6    163438     1     1
7    163550     1     1
8    163553     1     1
9    163654     1     1
10   163784     1     1
11   193585     1     1
12   194884     1     1
13   194943     1     1
14   194947     1     1
15   196274     1     1
16   363185     1     1
17   494408    NA    NA
18   494804     0     0
19   608018     1     1
20   608034     1     1

library(tidyverse)

df_na <- 
  dfd %>%
  pivot_longer(-position) %>%
  filter(is.na(value)) 

ggplot(df_na, aes(position, fill = name)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 500000, position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(163300,146203500,2920804
))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the `binwidth`? What about adjusting `bins` (Must say this is an unusually high binwidth`.

Comment: What does it look like if you don't set the binwidth or the x-axis breaks? What's the range of your actual data (what's included here wouldn't make sense with a bandwidth of 500k but I guess it might with the full set)? Also, you've set 51 breaks, which would be hard to fit well on an axis even if they were just 1–51, let alone 6+ digits.

Comment: I also don't know what you mean about the box width (binwidth?) being 300, since that's not the binwidth you set

Comment: Sorry @NelsonGon, I meant bin width (Ill edit that in the original post. That worked out perfectly I made the breaks=20 and the increased my bin width to equal that break size

Comment: Can you try geom_histogram() without specifying any arguments, including the bins.I believe the default number of bins is 30